# iOS 5 Wait for delegate to finish before populating a table?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios5

I am working on an iOS 5 app. I have a view controller that needs to display data as soon as its opened. The desired order of functionality is:

1. Call a web service
2. Wait for the reply from the web service (a delegate)
3. Fill a data array
4. Use the array to populate a list view
5. Show the list view

I have all of the components in place but after the web service call is made, the program doesn't wait for a reply (asynchronous call) and instead fills the list view with blanks since the data array is not quite ready.

So I need help with either (1) making the program wait until the delegate finishes filling the array and then populating the list view or (2) re-initializing the listview after the delegate has completed and re-populating the whole list view. If I move the list view (like a scroll down) I see the desired data because the view is re-initialized. So I know that I have all the components in place, I just need to make them work in the desired order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "an UITableView instance" by list view, then let the web service finish loading, then refresh the table view:

```
- (void) myWebServiceDidFinishLoadingData
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by "list" and "table" - I'm still new to working with iOS :). Thanks for your help, this answer did exactly what I needed and I'm marking it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, and no problem :) Good luck with further iOS development! You can check out my opensource iOS project on GitHub to learn from: https://github.com/H2CO3/