# How can I wait for a NSURLConnection delegate to finish before executing the next statement?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

This has been a hard one to search. 
I found a similar question, [iOS 5 Wait for delegate to finish before populating a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898231/ios-5-wait-for-delegate-to-finish-before-populating-a-table), but the accepted answer was 'Refresh the table view,' and that does not help me. The other results I found tended to be in c#.

I have an app that streams from iPhone to Wowza servers. When the user hits record, I generate a unique device id, then send it to a PHP script on the server that returns a JSON document with configuration settings (which includes the rtmp dump link).

The problem is, the delegate methods are asynchronous, but I need to get the config settings before the next lines of code in my `- (IBAction)recordButtonPressed` method, since that code is what sets the profile settings, and then records based on those settings.

I've realized I could make the `NSURLConnection` in `-recordButtonPressed` like I am currently, and then continue the setup code *inside* the delegate method `connectionDidFinishLoading` (or just encapsulate the setup and method call it from there) but that's sacrificing coherent design for functionality and that sucks.

Is there not some simple `waitUntilDelegateIsFinished:(BOOL)nonAsyncFlag` flag I can send to the delegator so I can have sequential operations that pull data from the web?

Comment: Do you mean you want a synchronous way to make the upload ?

Comment: The uploading is already handled. I just want a synchronous way to grab config settings from a php script before starting the recording.

Comment: Never wait in a UI thread.

Comment: I would suggest RestKit or AFNetworking. Handling `NSURLConnection` by yourself is really hard to get it right e.g. handling redirection. With those libraries you can also use block syntax which is very easier to chain the code like you want, and with RestKit you also get JSON dictionary as response or deserialization if you want.

Comment: This makes me realize how much more organized it would be to have the UI not on the main thread. Also, NSData's initWithContentsOfURL should be mentioned here. Still presents the issue of blocking the main thread or requiring threading- but it reduces the lines of code to a single statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've realized I could make the NSURLConnection in -recordButtonPressed like I am currently, and then continue the setup code inside the delegate method connectionDidFinishLoading (or just encapsulate the setup and method call it from there) but that's sacrificing coherent design for functionality and that sucks.

You have analyzed and understood the situation and you have described its possible solutions perfectly. I just don't agree with your conclusions. This kind of thing happens all the time:

```
- (void) doPart1 {
    // do something here that will eventually cause part2 to be called
}

- (void) doPart2 {
}
```

You can play various games with invocations to make this more elegant and universal, but my advice would be, don't fight the framework, as what you're describing is exactly the nature of being asynchronous. (And do *not* use a synchronous request on the main thread, since that blocks the main thread, which is a no-no.)

Indeed, in an event-driven framework, the very notion "wait until" is anathema.

Comment: This *really* helps. So would you say that explicit waiting is never necessary in iOS? Or does it have it's purposes?

Comment: I would say that explicit waiting *on the main thread* is never necessary - or legal. This is an event-driven framework. Your job is to prepare yourself to receive events, to ask to receive events, to arrange to receive events - but it is all about receiving events, whose order and timing you do not control. An entire chapter of my book is devoted to trying to get you to think the way the framework needs you to think: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch11.html

Comment: And in the particular case you are describing, the NSURLConnectionDelegate methods such as `connectionDidFinishLoading:` *are* how you "wait until". When and if the connection is finished, you'll get an event. You respond then. You do not sit twiddling your thumbs waiting; the framework is doing the waiting on a background thread for you.

Comment: Now I'm curious- since I should never block the main thread, why would anyone use sendSynchronousRequest? If you do it on a background thread, then you are basically just doing what any other networking object does.

Comment: And indeed I never do use it. One such scenario is suggested here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1693/_index.html but even that is only a kind of emergency measure due to a ported codebase.

Comment: Here too Apple pretty much says don't ever use it: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-SW3

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use [synchronous request](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest%3areturningResponse%3aerror%3a)?

Comment: Never use a synchronous request on the main thread. And if he does it on a background thread, we are back to exactly the same situation - he must be able to re-enter into the second part of his configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your asynchronous NSURLConnection request in a helper method which has a completion block as a parameter:

`-(void) asyncDoSomething:(void(^)(id result)completionHandler ;`

This method should be implemented in the `NSURLConnectionDelegate`. For details see the example implementation and comments below.

Elsewhere, in your action method:

Set the completion handler. The block will dispatch further on the main thread, and then perform anything appropriate to update the table data, unless the result was an error, in which case you should display an alert.

```
- (IBAction) recordButtonPressed 
{
    [someController asyncConnectionRequst:^(id result){
        if (![result isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // We are on the main thread!
                someController.tableData = result;
            });
        }    
    }];
}
```

The Implementation of the method `asyncConnectionRequst:` *could* work as follows: take the block and hold it in an ivar. When it is appropriate call it with the correct parameter. However, having blocks as ivars or properties will increase the risk to inadvertently introduce circular references.

But, there is a better way: a wrapper block will be immediately dispatched to a *suspended* serial dispatch queue - which is hold as an ivar. Since the queue is suspended, they will not execute any blocks. Only until after the queue will be resumed, the block executes. You resume the queue in your `connectionDidFinish:` and `connectionDidFailWithError:`  (see below):

In your NSURLConnectionDelegate:

```
-(void) asyncConnectionRequst:(void(^)(id result)completionHandler 
{
    // Setup and start the connection:
    self.connection = ...
    if (!self.connection) {
        NSError* error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"Me" 
                            code:-1234 
                        userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: @"Could not create NSURLConnection"}];
            completionHandler(error);
        });
        return;
    }
    dispatch_suspend(self.handlerQueue);  // a serial dispatch queue, now suspended
    dispatch_async(self.handlerQueue, ^{
        completionHandler(self.result);
    });
    [self.connection start];
}
```

Then in the NSURLConnectionDelegate, dispatch a the handler and resume the
handler queue:

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection {
    self.result = self.responseData;
    dispatch_resume(self.handlerQueue);
    dispatch_release(_handlerQueue), _handlerQueue = NULL;
}
```

Likewise when an error occurred:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    self.result = error;
    dispatch_resume(self.handlerQueue);
    dispatch_release(_handlerQueue), _handlerQueue = NULL;
}
```

There are even better ways, which however involve a few more basic helper classes which deal with asynchronous architectures which at the end of the day make your async code look like it were synchronous:

```
-(void) doFourTasksInAChainWith:(id)input
{
    // This runs completely asynchronous!

    self.promise = [self asyncWith:input]
    .then(^(id result1){return [self auth:result1]);}, nil)
    .then(^(id result2){return [self fetch:result2];}, nil)
    .then(^(id result3){return [self parse:result3];}, nil)
    .then(^(id result){ self.tableView.data = result; return nil;}, ^id(NSError* error){ ... })

    // later eventually, self.promise.get should contain the final result        
}
```